# Régua horizontal com texto

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer uma régua horizontal em HTML ou CSS com um texto no seu centro. Conheço apenas o comando `<HR>` do HTML, mas parece que ele não me deixa por um texto no seu centro.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Seria mais um divisor né ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser feito assim:

```css
.separator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.separator::before,
.separator::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.separator::before {
  margin-right: .25em;
}
.separator::after {
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">Hello World</div>
```

Se você quiser utilizar o `<hr>` pode utilizar o `content` para colocar o texto:

```css
 hr {
   padding: 0;
   border: none;
   border-top: medium double #333;
   color: #333;
   text-align: center;
 }
 hr:after {
   content: "Hello World 2";
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   top: -0.7em;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   padding: 0 0.25em;
   background: white;
 }
 height:30px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Aqui vai uma solução simulando uma `<hr>` com texto centralizado:

```css
.linhaComTexto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.linhaComTexto > span {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #F3F5F6;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="linhaComTexto">
  <span>Texto</span>
</div>
```

Retirado daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812830/4178863